# Fill a numpy 3D matrix from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with the following columns:

'value' |  'x' | 'y' | 'z' |

x,y,z are integers and value is a floating number.

I want to fill a numpy 3D matrix *mat*  with a given shape (compatible with the ranges of x, y and z) using the values in the dataframe. When the coordinates point to the same place in *mat*, I just want to add the values.

I can do this "manually" with for loops but is there a way to do this using pandas/numpy functions?

For example:

```
 'value' |  'x' | 'y' | 'z' |
 5.6     |   0  |  1  |  2  |
 -2      |   0  |  0  |  0  |
 3       |   0  |  1  |  2  |
```

should lead to *mat* with the following values:

```
mat[0,0,0] = -2
mat[0,1,2] = 8.6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might do something like this:

```
In [185]: target = np.zeros(df.iloc[:, 1:].max() + 1)

In [186]: np.add.at(target, df.iloc[:, 1:].T.values.tolist(), df["value"])

In [187]: target
Out[187]: 
array([[[-2. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  8.6]]])

In [188]: target.shape
Out[188]: (1, 2, 3)

In [189]: target[0, 0, 0]
Out[189]: -2.0

In [190]: target[0, 1, 2]
Out[190]: 8.5999999999999996
```

which builds an appropriately-sized target from the values, and then uses `np.add.at` to add to the target and handle duplicates appropriately.  The only tricky bit is that we need to transpose (to get the X coordinates together, etc.) and make a list so that the indices are interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I see at least two NumPy based ones. One would be with [`np.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html), which is already discussed in [`@DSM's post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47610846/3293881) and another with [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html). The implementation with `np.bincount` would look something like this -

```
def dataframe_to_array(df, out_shp):
    ids = np.ravel_multi_index(df[['x','y','z']].values.T, out_shp)
    val = df['value'].values
    return np.bincount(ids, val, minlength=np.prod(out_shp)).reshape(out_shp)
```

Sample run -

```
In [115]: df
Out[115]: 
   value  x  y  z
0    5.6  0  1  2
1   -2.0  0  0  0
2    3.0  0  1  2

In [116]: out = dataframe_to_array(df, (3,3,3))

In [117]: out[0,0,0]
Out[117]: -2.0

In [118]: out[0,1,2]
Out[118]: 8.5999999999999996
```

#### Benchmarking

`np.add.at` based from @DSM's solution -

```
def dataframe_to_array_addat(df, out_shp):
    target = np.zeros(out_shp)
    np.add.at(target, df[['x','y','z']].T.values.tolist(), df["value"])
    return target
```

Timings -

```
In [182]: N = 200 # dataset size/array shape decider

In [183]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,N,(100000,3)), 
                                     columns=[['x','y','z']])

In [184]: df['value'] = np.random.rand(df.shape[0])

In [185]: %timeit dataframe_to_array_addat(df, (N,N,N))
10 loops, best of 3: 36.1 ms per loop

In [186]: %timeit dataframe_to_array(df, (N,N,N))
100 loops, best of 3: 8.22 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain it like a pandas `loc_indexer` :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'value': {0: 5.6, 1: -2.0, 2: 3.0},
 'x': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0},
 'y': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1},
 'z': {0: 2, 1: 0, 2: 2}})
fields = list('xyz') 

mat = df.groupby(fields).sum().loc

In [9]: mat[0,0,0]
Out[9]: 
value   -2.0
Name: (0, 0, 0), dtype: float64

In [10]: mat[0,1,2]
Out[10]: 
value    8.6
Name: (0, 1, 2), dtype: float64
```

Or construct the true matrix :

```
mat2=np.full(df[fields].max()+1,np.nan)
for (x,y,z),v in mat.obj.iterrows(): mat2[x,y,z]=v
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need multiindex

```
df1=df.set_index(['x','y','z'])
df1.loc[(0,1,2)].sum()

Out[273]: 
value    8.6
```